# How do I serialize an object into JSON including defined variables in Racket?

Tags: json, racket

I am trying to to write a json structure to a file using racket. The actual function for writing works fine but when creating the data structure which I write to the file, I simply cannot figure out how to include values from bound variables.

```
    (start_location . "h")
    (end_location . "t")
    (ETA . 30)
    (route . ("g"))
    (optional_parameters . #hasheq((accessibility . #f)))
))

(define write-json-wrapper (lambda (jsexpr filename)
    (call-with-output-file filename (lambda (x) (write-json jsexpr x)) #:exists 'replace)
))
```

The above structure works when I write it to the file.

````
(define x "h")
(define b #hasheq(
    (start_location . x)
    (end_location . "t")
    (ETA . 30)
    (route . ("g"))
    (optional_parameters . #hasheq((accessibility . #f)))
))```

However when I try to use the value stored in x as the value for start_location it throws an error.

write-json: expected argument of type <legal JSON value>; given: 'x

Any help or explanation would be much appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#hasheq` is [literal for hash table](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-hashtable%29) and its content isn't evaluated:

> `#hasheq((a . 5) (b . 7))` reads equal to `(make-...eq '((b . 7) (a . 5)))`

If you want to use values of variables, you have to use [`make-hasheq`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._make-hasheq%29%29) like this:

```
#lang racket
(require json)

(define x 1)
(define y 2)
(define z 3)

(define jsexpr
  (make-hasheq (list (cons 'x x)
                     (cons 'y y)
                     (cons 'z z))))

(define write-json-wrapper (lambda (jsexpr filename)
    (call-with-output-file filename
      (lambda (x) (write-json jsexpr x)) #:exists 'replace)))
```

Example:

```
(write-json-wrapper jsexpr "foo.txt")
```

If you're familiar with [`quasiquote`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._quasiquote%29%29), you can do also this:

```
(define jsexpr
  (make-hasheq `((x . ,x)
                 (y . ,y)
                 (z . ,z))))
```

So for your data:

```
(make-hasheq `((start_location . ,x)
                 (end_location . "t")
                 (ETA . 30)
                 (route . ("g"))
                 (optional_parameters . #hasheq((accessibility . #f)))))
```

Comment: Since it doesn't look like the hash table is going to be mutated, it would be better to use immutable hash table. The `hash` function in particular makes it much easier to create such hash table. E.g., `(hash <key1> <val1> <key2> <val2>)` as opposed to `(make-hash (list (cons <key1> <val1>) (cons <key2> <val2>)))`

Comment: I tried both suggestions and it now works perfectly, thank you so much. Also thank you for the quasiquote example, I'll have to look into it more.